# Arduino takes input even when there is no supply to the input pin

Tags: arduino

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(2,INPUT);   //2nd pin as in put
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);    //onboard LED as output
}
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(13,digitalRead(2));    //When there is i/p glow, else does not
}
```

I wrote this code and connected one end of a wire to pin 2 of Arduino, other end left as it is, not connected to anywhere and LED started glowing. I have 2 clones of arduino, both did the same. Yes, I checked the arduino, works fine for other codes. Can some one explain me how arduino takes 5v input without supplying it ?
[image: Image of the Arduino, glowing LED, with wire not connected to supply]

The table is made of wood. I tried connecting 3mm led to 13th pin and ground, result was the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 5):

There is another input mode INPUT_PULLUP. Without it all "floating" inputs acts like a radio receiver so it catches all kinds of electrical interferences then.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the value of a pin that's not connected won't return anything meaningful, you'll have to either ground it or connect it to a voltage source.  (Or use a different pin mode)

Comment: That's my question, its not connected to anything but to an open wire, and the led glows !

Comment: The value returned from a read of an open pin without using a pullup mode will float randomly between min and max.  If it's floating closer to max the digitalRead will return a value of 1 (or HIGH), turning the LED on.